# Getting SQLiteException: Table not found

Tags: android, sqlite

My app crashes due to table not found error, what can be the reason for that?

> MainActivity

```
helper=new g_dbHelper((this));
SQLiteDatabase sql=helper.getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
values.put("NAME","Harry Potter");
values.put("PUBLISHER","Bloomberg Publications");
long newRowId = sql.insert("first",null,values);
String[] name={"NAME"};
SQLiteDatabase sql1=helper.getReadableDatabase();
try{
    Cursor cursor=sql1.query("first",name,null,null,null,null,null);
    int id=cursor.getColumnIndex("NAME");

    TextView txt=findViewById(R.id.textViewa);
    txt.setText(cursor.getString(id));
    cursor.close();
} catch(SQLiteException e) {
    Log.e("TAG","Problem in Reading");
}
```

> dbHelper

```
public class g_dbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper implements  BaseColumns {
    final static String DB_NAME="books.db";
    public g_dbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context,DB_NAME, null, 2);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {

        String create= "CREATE TABLE first ("+ BaseColumns._ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT, PUBLISHER TEXT);";
         try {
             sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(create);
         } catch (SQLiteException e) {
             Log.e("TAG","Table not created");
         }
    }
}
```

I have also tried changing the database version as well as uninstalling and reinstalling the app.

Comment: I think "semicolon" in create string is an error

Comment: thanks man........................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is nothing to do with the semi-colon.

The **table not found** is issued irrespective of the exception.

The actual exception appears to be `CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException` and this is due to the cursor not being moved to a row via a Cursor `move???` method before trying to retrieve the underlying data.

- When a Cursor is created it is positioned at **before the first row** (-1).
- See [Cursor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html) for Cursor move methods (`moveToFirst` has been used below.)

The code used:-

### g_dbHelper.java (added onUpgrade) :-

```
public class g_dbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper implements BaseColumns {
    final static String DB_NAME="books.db";
    public g_dbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context,DB_NAME, null, 2);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {

        String create= "CREATE TABLE first ("+ BaseColumns._ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT, PUBLISHER TEXT);";
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(create);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldversion, int newversion) {

    }
}
```

- Yes with the semi-colon at the end.

### MainActivty.java :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    g_dbHelper helper;
    TextView txt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        txt = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textviewa);
        SO48472717();
    }

    private void SO48472717() {
        helper = new g_dbHelper((this));
        SQLiteDatabase sql = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("NAME", "Harry Potter");
        values.put("PUBLISHER", "Bloomberg Publications");
        long newRowId = sql.insert("first", null, values);
        String[] name = {"NAME"};
        SQLiteDatabase sql1 = helper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = sql1.query("first", name, null, null, null, null, null);
        //########################### Fix Here.
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int id = cursor.getColumnIndex("NAME");
            txt.setText(cursor.getString(id));
        }
        //########################### End of Fix
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```

- NOTE the use of `if(cursor.moveToFirst) {....}`, without this you will get :-
  `android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1`

  - -1 indicating that the position is before a row.

#### Result :-

[image]

Comment: can you please elaborate your change

Comment: @HARDIKGARG edited answer re `if(cursor.moveToFirst) {....}`. But this doesn't result in table not found. If you still have issues then edit your question to include the stack trace from the log.

Comment: Oh I see why the **table not found**. You issue this in the catch, irrespective of the exception. You should  do `e.printStackTrace()` inside the catch it will then print the stack trace. There again as you see I've got rid of the try/catch. So at a guess it was the index out of bounds issue.

Answer (score 0):

Create Table query is malformed . and also there is no use of try catch in creating table cause it has to be done. below is the explanation.

```
 public static final String COL_NAME="_name";
public static final String COL_PUBLISHER="_publisher";
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
    String create= "CREATE TABLE first ("+ BaseColumns._ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+ COL_NAME+" TEXT, "+ COL_PUBLISHER +" TEXT)";
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(create);
}
```